# Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service stuck at stating/stopping. I did restart the service but no use then i did  delete the job and delete the service now I can't see the stating on the central admin option. Any help please.
[image]

[image]

Comment: the service is in Unprovision status, When i run the command to start the service it goes to Provision status also i get the error of Start-SPServiceInstance : A timer job can only be run on a server where the timer service is installed. this a custom server

Comment: Hi, Eric J. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

**Please follwoing steps:**

1. **Find the GUID of the problem service running in the particular server.**

   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

   Get-SPServiceInstance | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -eq 'Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service'}
2. **Run following command to start it.**

   Start-SPServiceInstance -identity "GUID"
3. **Run the following to check the status of the service. It should now be Online**.

   Get-SPServiceInstance -identity "GUID"
4. **If running above command did not change the status, try following commands.**

   $Var = Get-SpServiceInstance -identity "GUID"

   $Var.Unprovision()

----------------------------------- `Updated Answer` -----------------------------

Please check if the **SharePoint Timer Service** is **running**

[image]

If the **SharePoint Timer Service** from **Services** is stopped, although the timer service status in Central admin will be online, there will be problems with your server farm.

**Because it will stop running all timer jobs (alerts, workflow, UPA synchronization, etc.)**